# How to chain Underscore methods to populate an object from nested array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of objects - say, NFL teams. Each object (team) has a property - array of first names of team players.

```
var nflTeams = [
      { name: 'Kansas City Chiefs', playersFirstNames: ['Shane', 'Chad', 'Michael', 'Ronald', 'Blake', 'Noah'], champions: true },
      { name: 'Philadelphia Eagles', playersFirstNames: ['Jalen', 'Kenneth', 'Boston', 'Trey', 'Jack', 'Andre', 'Jack', 'Lane', 'Jason', 'Nakobe'], champions: false },
      { name: 'Cincinnati Bengals', playersFirstNames: ['Brandon', 'Joe', 'Chris', 'Joe', 'Tyler', 'Trenton', 'Trent', 'Mitchell', 'Alex', 'Trey', 'Ted'], champions: false },
      { name: 'San Francisco 49ers', playersFirstNames: ['Jimmy', 'Josh', 'Kyle', 'Jordan', 'Brandon', 'Danny', 'George', 'Tyler', 'Charlie', 'Jake', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Kevin'], champions: false },
    ];
```

Expected result - an object with an occurrence of first names: {'Joe': 1, 'Jimmy': 2, 'Jalen': 1 ....}

My goal is to achieve it through the use of Underscore methods such as _.map(), _.flatten(), _.reduce() all chained together using _.chain().

My current attempt miserably fails at _.reduce() stage:

```
var firstNameOccurence = { '{players firstName}': 0 };
    firstNameOccurence = _.chain (nflTeams)
      .map(function(team) {return team.playersFirstNames})
      .flatten()
      .reduce(function(newObject, firstName){
          console.log ('we have a first name of a player', firstName);
            return newObject[firstName] = 1 ? !newObject[firstName] :  newObject[firstName] += 1;
          
      }, {})
      .value();
```

Now it gives me just a boolean value of true. My ideal is try to use ternary expression because it looks more elegant. I tried using official Underscore documentation and some examples like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/underscore-js-_-reduce-function/), [this](https://vegibit.com/3-examples-of-the-underscore-reduce-function/) and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/underscorejs/underscorejs_reduce.htm).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `.reduce()` for this. Underscore.js has inbuilt methods that already perform what you're trying to do (ie: count the frequencies of items in an array), so you're better off using those instead of reinventing the wheel. What you can use is a combination of JavaScript's [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (annoyingly, underscore doesn't provide it, other utility libraries like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) do). And the [`_.countBy()`](https://underscorejs.org/#countBy) method:

```js
const nflTeams = [{ name: 'Kansas City Chiefs', playersFirstNames: ['Shane', 'Chad', 'Michael', 'Ronald', 'Blake', 'Noah'], champions: true }, { name: 'Philadelphia Eagles', playersFirstNames: ['Jalen', 'Kenneth', 'Boston', 'Trey', 'Jack', 'Andre', 'Jack', 'Lane', 'Jason', 'Nakobe'], champions: false }, { name: 'Cincinnati Bengals', playersFirstNames: ['Brandon', 'Joe', 'Chris', 'Joe', 'Tyler', 'Trenton', 'Trent', 'Mitchell', 'Alex', 'Trey', 'Ted'], champions: false }, { name: 'San Francisco 49ers', playersFirstNames: ['Jimmy', 'Josh', 'Kyle', 'Jordan', 'Brandon', 'Danny', 'George', 'Tyler', 'Charlie', 'Jake', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Kevin'], champions: false }, ];

const res = _.countBy(nflTeams.flatMap(team => team.playersFirstNames));
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.13.6/underscore-min.js" integrity="sha512-2V49R8ndaagCOnwmj8QnbT1Gz/rie17UouD9Re5WxbzRVUGoftCu5IuqqtAM9+UC3fwfHCSJR1hkzNQh/2wdtg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

If you don't want to use JavaScript's inbuilt `.flatMap()` method you can chain `.map()` and `.flatten()` like you have:

```js
const nflTeams = [{ name: 'Kansas City Chiefs', playersFirstNames: ['Shane', 'Chad', 'Michael', 'Ronald', 'Blake', 'Noah'], champions: true }, { name: 'Philadelphia Eagles', playersFirstNames: ['Jalen', 'Kenneth', 'Boston', 'Trey', 'Jack', 'Andre', 'Jack', 'Lane', 'Jason', 'Nakobe'], champions: false }, { name: 'Cincinnati Bengals', playersFirstNames: ['Brandon', 'Joe', 'Chris', 'Joe', 'Tyler', 'Trenton', 'Trent', 'Mitchell', 'Alex', 'Trey', 'Ted'], champions: false }, { name: 'San Francisco 49ers', playersFirstNames: ['Jimmy', 'Josh', 'Kyle', 'Jordan', 'Brandon', 'Danny', 'George', 'Tyler', 'Charlie', 'Jake', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Kevin'], champions: false }, ];

const res = _.chain(nflTeams).map('playersFirstNames').flatten().countBy().value();
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.13.6/underscore-min.js" integrity="sha512-2V49R8ndaagCOnwmj8QnbT1Gz/rie17UouD9Re5WxbzRVUGoftCu5IuqqtAM9+UC3fwfHCSJR1hkzNQh/2wdtg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

---

As for your attempt, I suggest looking into how the core operators of JavaScript work before looking into more complicated concepts like `.reduce()`, which includes `=` (assignment), `!` (negation), `? :` (ternary) etc. In your attempt, you're doing `newObject[firstName] = 1 ?` which assigns the value of `1` to the `firstName` property of your object as well as evaluates to the value of `1`. That means the true portion of your ternary will always be evaluated and will be the thing you're returning. In your case, that's  `!newObject[firstName]`. As you just set this to `1`, you're negating it with `!`, and `!1` is `false`. This results in your returning `false`. Then, on the next iteration, `.reduce()` calls your callback with `newObject` set to the `false` value you just returned. It's no longer an object. Again, your code now attempts to set a property `firstName` on `newObject` with `newObject[firstName] = 1`. As this is equivalent to `false[firstName] = 1`, it evaluates to `1`, but leaves `newObject` (ie: `false`) unmodified. When `!newObject[firstName]` runs again, it's unable to find the property `firstName` on the `false` value so it ends up returning `!undefined`, ie: `true`. This continues until all your iterations are completed.

As you can see, your current logic in your `.reduce()` callback doesn't make much sense, as you're trying to return a boolean rather than an object, which is what you want your final result to be:

```js
const nflTeams = [{ name: 'Kansas City Chiefs', playersFirstNames: ['Shane', 'Chad', 'Michael', 'Ronald', 'Blake', 'Noah'], champions: true }, { name: 'Philadelphia Eagles', playersFirstNames: ['Jalen', 'Kenneth', 'Boston', 'Trey', 'Jack', 'Andre', 'Jack', 'Lane', 'Jason', 'Nakobe'], champions: false }, { name: 'Cincinnati Bengals', playersFirstNames: ['Brandon', 'Joe', 'Chris', 'Joe', 'Tyler', 'Trenton', 'Trent', 'Mitchell', 'Alex', 'Trey', 'Ted'], champions: false }, { name: 'San Francisco 49ers', playersFirstNames: ['Jimmy', 'Josh', 'Kyle', 'Jordan', 'Brandon', 'Danny', 'George', 'Tyler', 'Charlie', 'Jake', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Kevin'], champions: false }, ];

const res = _.chain(nflTeams)
  .map('playersFirstNames')
  .flatten()
  .reduce((currObject, firstName) => { // ((currObject, firstName)) => ({...currObject, [firstName]: (currObject[firstName] || 0) + 1}) as the callback would also work here and it'd be more concise, however, it is less efficient as it creates a new object for each iteration as well as iterates all existing properties of `currObject` per loop.
    currObject[firstName] = (currObject[firstName] || 0) + 1;
    return currObject;
  }, {})
  .value();
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.13.6/underscore-min.js" integrity="sha512-2V49R8ndaagCOnwmj8QnbT1Gz/rie17UouD9Re5WxbzRVUGoftCu5IuqqtAM9+UC3fwfHCSJR1hkzNQh/2wdtg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Good answer! You can be even more concise with `_.map`, though. Thanks to iteratee shorthands, you can do `.map('playersFirstNames')` instead of the equivalent arrow function.

Comment: Your answer is to the point. It took me a while to go through my mistakes, but now it makes sense.

Comment: @curious_orange No worries, if you feel like this answers your question you can accept the answer by using the grey check mark in the top left corner of the answer